# what would be the mechanism for these reactions?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, nucleophilic-substitution

I believe the first one would have an intramolecular attack by the sulfur inverting the stereochem followed by an attack by OH- but I can’t get the second one.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sodium nitrate/HCl is standard conditions for the diazotisation of primary amines. You may have seen this done with anilines, but it works generally for primary alkyl amines. The diazo group is then displaced by chloride. As reported [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6862327/) the reaction goes with retention of stereochemistry. If you use a less nucelophilic acid e.g. Aq. sulfuric acid you get the hydroxyacid again with retention

Comment: What about the first equation, the guessed mechanism is totally wrong if I'm not mistaken.